# How to prevent firebase-query element to updating the data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymerfire

I am using polymer and firebase to create a web app. To get a list in the database, I am using the "firebase-query" element of polymerfire.

Now, the list of items I am getting from the database is posts that people are posting on my app. Now I have the firebase-query element like this:

```
<firebase-query
  id="query"
  path="/posts"
  limit-to-last="15"
  data="{{posts}}">
</firebase-query>
```

and I have `dom-repeat` template tag to display the posts like this

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[posts]]" as="post">
  <div>[[post.content]]</div>
</template>
```

Now, if I have bunch of people posting a lot of contents at once, this list would be updating every second, and it would be hard to read.

Is there a way to prevent `firebase-query` element to stop updating once the initial load is complete, and possibly updating again when I call a certain function?

I tried to add a disabled attribute, but that just deletes whatever is inside the `data` attribute (`{{posts}}` in my case), so when disabled is set, nothing shows up on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with firebase-query, but you can do simple trick. On property `posts` set `observer` function.

```
posts: {
 Type: Array,
 value: function(){return []},
 observer: "debouncePosts"
}
```

then in js you can define debounce function where I set, for example, 10 000 miliseconds (10 seconds) and called some callback function where I set `this.posts` to `currentPosts` property which will be rendered in `template`.

```
debouncePosts: function(data) {
  this.debounce("debouncePost", function(){
    this.set("currentPosts", this.posts);
  }.bind(this), 10000)
}
```

and html template will be like:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[currentPosts]]" as="post">
  <div>[[post.content]]</div>
</template>
```

documentation to debounce: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-debounce

If you like to do it in different way like update data whenever user presses update, it's really easy now for you. Just set on-tap on some button and then in function you will do something like `this.set("currentPosts", this.posts)`

Comment: I tried to make a function that includes this:
this.set("currentPosts", this.posts)
but the dom-repeat template did not update...